# image and text in listobx

Tags: wpf, image, text, listbox

I want to inesrt one image beside one text,like this I have to include three items in a `ListBox` in run time.

If the number of items is more than 3,then the last items get removed.
How can I do that in WPF,C#.
And the newly added item should get added in first place.
Now I did up to include text at runtime.

```
if (listBox1.Items.Count >= 3)
                listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(2);
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0,lData);
```

But I do nto know how to insert image(small rectangle with red colr,green color)

Answer (score 0):

Anu, you might want to read about `DataTemplate`-s (e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) and about styling and templating in WPF in general.